# After running query in phpmyadmin (xampp) when I click on Create view I get error 404

Tags: php, sql

```
SELECT 
    make, 
    MIN(price) AS minimum, 
    MAX(price) AS maximum, 
    MAX(price) - MIN(price) AS price_range, 
    AVG(price) AS average, 
    COUNT(price) AS count 
FROM 
    cars 
    INNER JOIN makes USING (make_id) 
GROUP BY 
    make;
```

query runs fine but create view (phpmyadmin ver 4.7.9) brings this error:

```
Error in processing request
Error code: 404
Error text: Not Found (rejected)
```

It seems that the connection to server has been lost. Please check your network connectivity and server status.

Comment: side note: have phpmyadmin ver. 4.7.4 at home and it does fine with now errors. I am following a lesson online trying to learn this. what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Because there a lot of things that could be causing this I would advice you in the direction of reinstalling PMA to see if this fixes your issue. It might be just some installation issue.

Comment: If this is a fresh XAMPP install you might want to reinstall the complete thing. Just back  your files up and be sure to get the latest XAMPP version. I am not sure about how to go in order to reinstall only the PMA from XAMPP.

Answer (score 0):

I´ve been experiencing the same problem. My solution was quite simple: In PHPmyAdmin/SQL Edit, before de command SELECT just write de command CREATE VIEW

Comment: what ? no complete step please .....